# Selenium Wait until element is visible issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Got problem with proper method for waiting until element is visible.

Let me describe how page works. Page is loaded, dropdown is shown, but then, there is progress bar appearing (jquery block UI), because data is loaded from db, according to some conditions.

So i used two methods, one for wait for element to be present, then wait to dissapear, but on some occassions (maybe there are loaded in other way, etc.) i got Internet Explorer crash (so no exception by selenium, but crash of IE). Below methods and execution:

```
public IWebElement WaitForPageElementToLoad(By by, IWebDriver driver, int timeInSeconds)
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeInSeconds));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
                return driver.FindElement(by);
            }

public void WaitForPageElementToBeRemoved(By by, IWebDriver driver, int timeInSeconds)
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeInSeconds));
                wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IWebElement element = d.FindElement(by);
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Execution:

```
WaitForPageElementToLoad(By.XPath("//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']"), ieDriver, 25);
WaitForPageElementToBeRemoved(By.XPath("//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']"), ieDriver, 25);
WaitForPageElementToLoad(By.Id("clientSelector"), ieDriver, 25);
```

I think webdriver is searching through elements during some work, i do not how to figure that out, to write it properly. Maybe you'll have some hints, etc.

Comment: IE Crashed or the IEDriver crashed?

Comment: IE crashed, got even a message from IE, that it stop working. I can close, debug, etc.

Comment: Have you tried against Firefox or chrome to validate if your code is working or if it causes other issues?

Comment: Yes, i used Chrome driver and there i received "normal" exception: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (390, 611). Other element would receive the click: <div class="blockUI blockOverlay"> So the problem is with IE (i used IE 11), which crashes instead of showing such exception. Another thing is solving such exception itself. It's written in knockout.js and sometimes first appears on UI dropdown, then progress, but sometimes i can see progress at first (it's just what i can see, page could faster load things, depending on traffic i suppose).